# Is annoying a synonym of boring?

Tags: synonyms, translation, paraphrasing

I know boring means uninteresting or dull, and annoying means irritating or bothering, for me they are totally different, so I was surprised to see "bore" being translated as "使厌烦"(which means annoying somebody) in most English-Chinese bilingual dictionaries(Oxford, Cambridge, Longman etc.).

I wonder if they are synonyms.

Comment: In English the two have different meaning. The question is whether or not there are different words for them in Chinese

Comment: Somebody who is **boring** *can* be **annoying**. But so can somebody who is **loud**, **repetitive**, or **dishonest**. That doesn't mean that the words are synonyms—they aren't.

Comment: @Eran no, I'm asking whether they are different in English, just to know if the translations are correct.

Comment: You've accepted the solitary answer after only an hour, not waiting to see if there were alternative explanations. *For instance*... **bore** is also a *noun*, and [one definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bore) is "a tedious or *annoying* situation or activity" [my emphasis].

Comment: If the roof of my house fell in, the week before Christmas, just as I was expecting the family to arrive, it would, to say the least be "annoying". But I doubt it would be "boring".

Comment: I think the problem is your definition of 厌烦 is wrong. All four of the bilingual Chinese-English dictionaries I have available to hand translate it the same way I would: ‘be fed up with, be sick of, be bored with, have had enough of’. One even has an example usage with 使: 「他使我厌烦死了」 translated as “He bored me to death”. Boring someone is of course one way of annoying someone, but 使厌烦 doesn’t _mean_ ‘annoy’ as such in standard Mandarin. That would be 烦人 or 烦恼 or something along those lines instead. Or even just 烦 (「烦死我了！」 “How annoying!”).

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet I think the correct translation of boring or dull is 无聊. 厌烦 definitely means irritaing or annoying. And "He bored me to death" for me is "he is so boring and I can't stand it", which should be translated as "他无聊死我了", I know it's weird in Chinese, but it should be like this and I'm a native speaker of Chinese.

Comment: @linly Well, the people who write the dictionaries clearly disagree with you, since they don’t list ‘annoy’ as a translation. 无聊 generally describes the thing that is boring, whereas 厌烦 describes the person who’s fed up. And as I said, boring someone is one way of annoying them; being fed up is what happens when something annoys you persistently until you’ve had enough. “He bores me to death” in English normally means that he kept talking about something very boring for so long that I thought he was going to die.

Comment: To put it differently: with _annoy/irritate_ (and 烦), it’s the thing itself that causes a negative reaction in you. With _be fed up/sick of_ (and 厌烦, at least according to the dictionaries and my experience), it’s the _persistence_ and/or _repetition_ of the thing that causes the negative reaction (and causes the thing to become annoying). You can like a song (it’s not annoying), but if you listen to it a hundred times, you’ll be fed up with it (it becomes annoying). Googling the phrase “听得我都厌烦了” shows many examples of precisely this usage.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet You are right, 厌烦 does have a bit of "being tired of", and bore(the verb) means causing weariness through lack of interest. This explans the translation. Thank you!

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet But in my experience, 厌烦 is a little bit too strong in these senarios, the word itself emphasizes on disgust or dislike, maybe 厌倦 is closer but still different from feeling weary due to lack of interest. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @linly Yes, I’d say 厌倦 is more like ‘be tired of/be fed up with’ and 厌烦 is more like ‘be sick and tired of’.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Oxford Living Dictionary these adjectives are not synonyms.

> [BORING](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/boring):
>
> Not interesting; tedious.
>   - *‘I've got a boring job in an office’*
>
> (Synonyms: tedious, dull, monotonous).

vs

> [ANNOYING](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/annoying):
>
> Causing irritation or annoyance.
>   - *‘unsolicited calls are annoying’*
>
> (Synonyms: irritating, infuriating, exasperating, maddening,
>   trying, tiresome, troublesome, bothersome, irksome, vexing, vexatious,
>   galling, provoking, displeasing).

Answer (score 2):

I think in posh British circles (especially in earlier centuries) to say someone is a bore means that they are annoying. If the book you’re reading refers to upper class British people then the translation you have is probably correct. However, in American English boring and annoying are two different ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the definitions of the two words and you may find, though they use different words to describe them, they seem to be talking about the same thing. One might lead to the other (as an inference), but that is not necessary and native speakers would not confuse these for each other. The primary difference is that:

- 'annoying' is something that is actively bothering you. A loud noise, or something that keeps interrupting you.
- 'boring' is something that is dull and lifeless, or at least seems so to you.

Both are things that you'd rather stop, but you wouldn't mistake one for the other, and so you wouldn't consider them synonyms. Of course something that is boring may well be annoying you (because it is so boring), but that doesn't make the two concepts the same.

Note that even if the lists of synonyms for each overlap, that doesn't guarantee that they are synonymous. (in mathematical terms, synonymy sounds like it should be an 'equivalence relation' but is not. 'synonymy' is more like 'near' rather than 'equal to'.